# ESTA Transiting first, then entering the US

Tags: esta

I need help with one of the questions on the ESTA application form.
'Is your travel to the US occurring in transit to another country?'

I am flying in on the 3rd February from Sydney Australia to Vancouver Canada, transiting in San Francisco. Then I will fly on 17th February from Vancouver to Boston and staying in Boston.

Do I answer yes or no to this question?

Does the question on the ESTA application form 'Is your travel to the US occurring in transit to another country?' asking about the first entry into the USA? or for the entire trip.

If someone could just let me know whether I answer 'yes' or 'no' that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Flagged a possible duplicate after thinking, I'm not sure if it's exactly the same answer though, but at least the link is there.

Answer (score 3):

It's asking about the first entry.

The next time you enter the US (on the 17th) is a separate trip.

Once you've 'activated' on arriving, it then covers you for the next 90 days, including arriving by land.  However, if asked about it, do mention it to the officer when you arrive.

I have links, but I think the answers in [If I have an ESTA approved for transit, can I visit a second time as a tourist?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/39050/101), while not quite the same question, will address what you're wondering as well.

While the US doesn't have the same concept of 'transit' as other countries (you'll still go through immigration) - since it's a transit between flights, you'll still answer yes to this.

Comment: "Once you've 'activated' on arriving, it then covers you for the next 90 days": this is true only if you remain in Canada, Mexico, and the Caribbean.